# Sonar analysis in preview mode does not fail if new issues are found

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.6

When I run sonar against my project in preview mode, the build is successful even when issues are found and listed in the issues-report-light.html. Is that the default behaviour? The build fails for the same issues when run in analysis mode.
Am I missing a setting?

Answer (score 0):

that's normal. Sonarqube will not break the build since 5.2 in preview mode. Issues will be just listed in console or html report.

You say it fails when analysis mode, so you mean you have defined a Quality Gate. A QG will only work with analysis mode, so all you say is the default and correct behaviour. yes.